# Telerik ORM Cannot find resource embedded in assembly , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-open-access

Im using telerik ORM and stuck on error

```
"Cannot find resource dcModNews.rlinq embedded in assembly IbizaVuela, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

IbizaVuela is my project name dcModNews.rlinq exists in project
I have tried couple of solutions mentioned on telerik support but all in vain 
any one help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ORM of telerik to get rid of this error basically it requires the enviorment in vs to run telerik c